# Solution of this system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

What are the solutions of the following system of linear equations for $a\in\mathbb{R} $?

$a^2x+2ay=3a$

$2ax+a^2y=-3a$

Comment: If $a=2$ there's a problem... what have you tried?

Comment: For $a=0$ there is an unlimited number of solutions because $0=0$. I can  also see that if $a=2$ there is a problem, but how can i calculate it?

Comment: Well if $a\neq 0$ you could divide through by $a$ remember $2$ is a problem too.

Comment: I guess you should think about when $a$ is a problem before solving.  Then use any method you like ( substitution, eliminating, matrix inverse)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If $a=0$, the system becomes $0=0$ and admits an infinite amount of solutions. Assuming $a \ne 0$ we can divide both sides by $a$ to get
$$
\begin{pmatrix}a & 2 \\ 2 & a \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}3 \\ -3 \end{pmatrix}
$$
so now apply Gaussian elimination. Can you finish the problem? You should see immediately that when $a=2$, the equations on the LHS become the same...

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

For $a \ne 0$ your system become:
$$
\begin{cases}
ax+2y=3\\
2x+ay=-3
\end{cases}
$$and, solving the first equation for $y$ and substituting in the second equation you find:
$$
x(a^2-4)=3(a+2)
$$
can you discuss the solutions of this equation? what happens if $a=\pm 2$?

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much. So I have to discuss the cases $a\neq2$ and $a\neq-2$

Comment: The case $a=2$ or $a=-2$ !. and you can have infinite or no solutions. For $a \ne \pm 2$ the system has one solution.

Comment: In that case: for $a=-2$ infinite solutions and for $a=2$ no solution because $0=12$.

Comment: Yes. all right! :)

Answer (score -1):

If $a=0$ infinitely many solutions. If $a=-2$, the same thing happening. If $a \ne 0$ and $a \ne -2$, we can get $x=-y$ and then we can solve easily.